# Using Regex to match on multiple possible values unless ignored values match

Tags: regex, iis, logging, notepad++

I'm trying to find a better way of pulling information from my log files using notepad++ and regex, so that I can view anything of concern (looking for 500 errors and php attempts etc).

Currently I've got the following;

> ^((?!bot.php)|(?!baidu)|(?!bingbot)|(?!facebookexternalhit)|(?!Curious+George)|(?!wpad.dat)).*(php.*$|select.*$|/wp.*$|wordpress.*$|\s500\s.*$|/Rejected.*$)

Which as I understand it should be ignoring the lines with the first values (various bots I want to ignore and proxy attempts that i'm not concern with)
but for it then to match on the other values (php, wordpress, 500 errors and rejected from urlscan), but whilst it's matching on the second group, it seems to fail on ignoring values in the first group.

(As a note before anybody asks why I'm looking for PHP in server logs, I'm running a windows server on .net so any .PHP is either headers from bots or hacking attempts to find non-existent pages)

Comment: Can you provide a example of match & non-match items for tests purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression in notepad++

`(?-s)^(?=(?:.(?!baidu|bot\.php))*?$)(?=.*?(?:\.php|select\.|500)).*?$`

where `(?!baidu|bot\.php)` contains an alternated blacklist (lines you want to ignore)
and `(?:\.php|select\.|500)` contains a whitelist of lines you want to match.

It will only match lines that match in the whitelist but also do not match the blacklist.

e.g. only matches lines 2 and 4 of the following 4 lines:

```
/randomPage.htm randomBrowser 200 
/access.php randomBrowser 200 
/access.php baidu 200 
/randomPage.htm randomBrowser 500
```

Comment: That's spot on, it's gone from 50,000+ returns to a few thousand, much more manageable .